# JUnit timeout on @BeforeClass

Tags: java, junit

Tests in JUnit, annotated with @Test can have a timeout set in ms, for example:

```
@Test(timeout = 1000)
public void testSomething(){
    ....
}
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to put a timeout on the setup (or @BeforeClass).

Is there any other sensible way to do this? I wonder if there is some reason @BeforeClass cannot have a timeout?

I would like to do this:

```
@BeforeClass(timeout = 1000) // <-- Not currently possible
public static void setup(){
    doSomethingWhichMayRunForever();
}
```

Edit: added 'static'

Comment: Why would you want to do that? `@BeforeClass` only setup the class for execute the tests, is not a test itself.

Comment: Good question. The reason I would like to do this is because I am running some other process, for which I cannot see the source code or call individual parts of, and I wish to test the output of this process with several tests checking the correctness of the output.

Therefore, the plan (although technically not unit testing), is to run the process in the @BeforeClass, then to have several tests, each of which checks something in particular in the output. Ideally, I would not want to run the process many times. A very strange use case I am sure.

Comment: There is only one "test run" so to speak, but there are several things being checked. I realise this isn't good unit testing practice, but it is a necessity.

Comment: Can you have a instance variable loaded using a test with timeout and verify that instance variable using other unit tests?

Comment: But, are you testing that "external" processes or your specific components that check these processes output?

Comment: I should be clearer on the exact situation. I'm wanting to test student submissions for basic coursework exercises. Whilst some unit tests are in place, this is for more generic (overall input/output) testing. This is because only certain methods have been forced into student submissions (e.g, for this task you must implement this interface - therefore we know we can test those methods directly), but they will have many of their own methods too, named as they wish and doing whatever the purpose of that particular method is.

Comment: Therefore, the purpose of the "doSomethingWhichMayRunForever()", is to run the submission in this case. I realise an alternative which is to run it in a separate process with a timeout beforehand, that is fine, but it would be easier if there was some straight forwards timeout on the @BeforeClass. This would allow me to call StudentSubmission.main directly.

Answer (score 1):

I found some code related to the same in gitHub below. I had a scenario in our application as well to have timeout in @BeforeClass. I read its not a good practise to have conditions / logic added in @BeforeClass based annotated method. So, i handled condition in each @Test method.

See the link if it helps :

https://github.com/jaruk/junit/commit/c5176f18139b9b99dfbc6540d4a6b6a8f049e568

Comment: This looks handy, I will have a look into it (It'll take me some time to get my head around what's going on). I understand it's not 'good practice' and should be avoided where possible.

Answer (score 1):

**In JUnit marking the whole class for timeout is not possible**.

In TestNG you can achieve that by anotating the test class with `@Test` annotation:

```
@Test(timeOut = 500)
public class Mavenproject1Suite {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JUnit, method annotated with @BeforeClass must be static, i wondered how your method can be executed without it

Comment: Thanks - correct, my question was just using an example.I have updated the question slightly.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can do is provide a timeout at the test class level:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public final class MyTest {
  @ClassRule
  public static Timeout classTimeout = new Timeout(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  @BeforeClass
  public static void setup(){
    doSomethingWhichMayRunForever();
  }

  @Test
  public void test1() throws Exception {
    // Your test code here
  }
}
```